# outer loop is not executing in this procedure ,please suggest me what to do?

Tags: mysql

```
drop procedure if exists insertCampaignTimes;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE insertCampTimes()  
BEGIN

     DECLARE dayNo INT DEFAULT 1; 
     DECLARE hourNo INT DEFAULT 3; 

DELETE FROM `camp_time`  where camp_id = 416;

 WHILE (hourNo <= 3) 
   DO
     WHILE (hourNo <= 15) 
       DO
       INSERT INTO `camp_time` (`camp_id`, `day`, `hour`) values (416, dayNo, hourNo);
       SET hourNo := hourNo + 1;
     END WHILE;

  SET dayNo := dayNo + 2; 
 END WHILE;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it is executing for 1 day not for day 2-7.

Comment: after the inner loop `WHILE (hourNo <= 15)` , `hourNo` will be equal to `16` so the outer loop condition will be `false`, so after the end of the inner loop, you should reset the `hourNo`

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating **hourNo** field out side the inner loop. Like both loop you are using same **hourNo** field. UPdate your code with one more `SET hourNo := hourNo + 1;` after first *end while*.

Comment: Share ur Updated SP